# Where is the KDE of Kubuntu 64bit?

Tags: kde, kubuntu

I have just installed Kubuntu 64bit linux(`kubuntu-10.04-dvd-amd64.iso`).
When it is opened i couldn't pass to the visual screen. I installed startx packages but not i don't see the KDE desktop.

How can i install or call KDE desktop to use(and manage) linux machine?

Comment: Are you getting any error messages in the log files specificly xorg? you may have a problem with graphics starting up and therefore it falls back to the command prompt

Comment: No, there is no error. I installed startx but i thought i will get kde desktop. There is just one terminal window and i can run programs with writing their executable file names.

Answer (score 0):

What does your xorg log say?  The default log file is /var/log/Xorg.n.log on most platforms, where n is the display number of the Xorg server.

Comment: Now i executed `apt-get install kubuntu-desktop` command. Now it is downloading kde desktop.

Comment: Ah, I'd assumed that you'd installed the standard desktop edition...  Yes, that's an important package if you want a desktop!